# Using embedding of ${L^\infty }(0,1)$ in ${H^1}(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to ask you about a proof that I found strange.
Let $f,g \in H_0^2(0,L)$ and let $$h = {\left( {{f_x}} \right)^2} - {\left( {{g_x}} \right)^2}$$
we have
$${\left\| h \right\|_{H_0^1(0,1)}} = {\left\| {{{\left( {{f_x}} \right)}^2} - {{\left( {{g_x}} \right)}^2}} \right\|_{H_0^1(0,1)}} = {\left\| {\left( {{f_x} - {g_x}} \right)\left( {{f_x} + {g_x}} \right)} \right\|_{H_0^1(0,1)}}$$
Can I say  that 
$${\left\| {\left( {{f_x} - {g_x}} \right)\left( {{f_x} + {g_x}} \right)} \right\|_{H_0^1(0,1)}} \leqslant {\left\| {\left( {{f_x} + {g_x}} \right)} \right\|_{{L^\infty }(0,1)}}{\left\| {\left( {{f_x} - {g_x}} \right)} \right\|_{H_0^1(0,1)}}$$ ?
thanks.

Comment: what does the index $x$ in $f_x$ mean ?

Comment: the derevative of $f$ with respect to $x$

Comment: I guess you need to estimate $\|(f_x-g_x)(f_{xx}+g_{xx})\|_{L^2}.$

Comment: thank you sir, i found the answer, it is enough to write things in a simplest why.